# What could "by" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning

The width of the means of escape will normally exceed the width of the exit doors by the width of the doorframe.

Comment: *"By"* can have lots of meanings, but many online dictionaries and resources list the relevant one. Which ones have you looked at?

Comment: @JHCL Collins and Cambridge English Dictionary. I'v got the meaning now with the example sentence provided below. It's very interesting for a non-native speaker to learn about these seemingly simple words in very different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the hell are you reading!

Anyway:

I assume it means that if there were no door frame, the means of escape (a car, one would think) could just squeeze through those exit doors.

The "by" is just, well, "by".

If A is 10 feet long
and B is 15 feet long
then the length of B exceeds the length of A
**by** 5 feet.

Comment: Thanks Ricky. I got what you said by your example sentence. My sentence is from a technical book about theater construction.